# cakephp validation losing parameters

Tags: cakephp, validation, parameter-passing

CONTROLLER

```
class ImagesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Images';
    var $uses = array('Image','Person');
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');


        function add($idp = 0, $mac = 0) 
        {


            if (!empty($this->data) &&
                 is_uploaded_file($this->data['Image']['File']['tmp_name'])) {
                $fileData = fread(fopen($this->data['Image']['File']['tmp_name'], "r"),
                                         $this->data['Image']['File']['size']);

                $this->data['Image']['name'] = $this->data['Image']['File']['name'];
                $this->data['Image']['type'] = $this->data['Image']['File']['type'];
                $this->data['Image']['size'] = $this->data['Image']['File']['size'];
                $this->data['Image']['data'] = $fileData;
                $this->data['Image']['people_id'] = $idp;

                $this->Image->save($this->data);

                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'People', 'action' => 'welcome',$mac));   

            }

        }
```

When I validate the form, I lose both parameters $idp and $mac.. How can I make them persist?

VIEW

```
<?php
    echo $form->create('Image', array('action' => 'add', 'type' => 'file'));
    echo $form->file('File');
    echo $form->submit('Upload');
    echo $form->end();
?>
```

Comment: Validate thru Cake or JavaScript? `$mac` shouldn't lose scope inside the `if`. Something is happening before.

Comment: We need much more details to answer this. `$mac` is not going anywhere in this example. When exactly does it disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following in your form element:

```
'url'=>$this->Html->url()
```

So the form will look like:

```
echo $form->create('Image', array('type' => 'file', 'url'=>$this->Html->url()));
```

Basically the $this->Html->url() get the current url with parameters and you pass it into the action of the form and if you submit in the same action (as it usually does) this should keep your parameters in tact.

HTH